# Shared registry location for all Domain Controllers

Tags: active-directory, registry, windows-server, domaincontroller

I have a service that would run on all domain controllers of a particular windows domain in to which its installed.

I have settings which the services rely upon, and I want to put this in a registry location where it can be shared. Is their any way I can achieve this?

Basically a shared registry location for all domain controllers, So that when any of my services change my registry, all my services could immediately see the change.

Answer (score 0):

[SYSVOL](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8548.sysvol-and-netlogon-share-importance-in-active-directory.aspx) solved this. Its replicated across domain controllers.